# How to get sys.exc_traceback form IPython shell.run_code?

Tags: qt, console, ipython

My app interfaces with the IPython Qt shell with code something like this:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import ExecutionResult
shell = self.kernelApp.shell # ZMQInteractiveShell
code = compile(script, file_name, 'exec')
result = ExecutionResult()
shell.run_code(code, result=result)
if result:
    self.show_result(result)
```

The problem is: how can show_result show the traceback resulting from exceptions in code?

Neither the `error_before_exec` nor the `error_in_exec` ivars of ExecutionResult seem to give references to the traceback.  Similarly, neither `sys` nor `shell.user_ns.namespace.get('sys')` have `sys.exc_traceback` attributes.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Edward

Answer (score 0):

`IPython/core/interactiveshell.py` contains `InteractiveShell._showtraceback`:

```
def _showtraceback(self, etype, evalue, stb):
    """Actually show a traceback. Subclasses may override..."""
    print(self.InteractiveTB.stb2text(stb), file=io.stdout)
```

The solution is to monkey-patch IS._showtraceback so that it writes to sys.stdout (the Qt console):

```
from __future__ import print_function
...
shell = self.kernelApp.shell # ZMQInteractiveShell
code = compile(script, file_name, 'exec')

def show_traceback(etype, evalue, stb, shell=shell):
    print(shell.InteractiveTB.stb2text(stb), file=sys.stderr)
    sys.stderr.flush() # <==== Oh, so important

old_show = getattr(shell, '_showtraceback', None)
shell._showtraceback = show_traceback
shell.run_code(code)
if old_show: shell._showtraceback = old_show
```

**Note**: there is no need to pass an ExecutionResult object to shell.run_code().

EKR